# C# Outlook AddIn 2010 cannot read UserDefinedProperty

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-2007

I have defined four custom user properties and i can not access to the in order to get their data, custom properties are present in outlook appointment but i can get to them :

[image]

My c# code below :

```
        Outlook.ItemProperties itemProp = appointmentItem.ItemProperties;
        foreach (Outlook.ItemProperty userprop in itemProp)
        {
            if (userprop.IsUserProperty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(userprop.Name + "\t" + userprop.Value);
            }
        }
```

I have used an api([JWebServices](http://www.independentsoft.de/jwebservices/)) that creates appointment event into Outlook(2007 my version), in my code below i have created some CustomProperties, called in C# Addin Outlook UserPropertie.
I still can get the value of custom users properties that i have defined from the java side

```
    PropertyName myRdvTypePropertyName = new PropertyName("RdvType", StandardPropertySet.PUBLIC_STRINGS);
    ExtendedProperty myRdvTypeExtendedProperty = new ExtendedProperty(myRdvTypePropertyName, event.getTyperdv());
    appointment.getExtendedProperties().add(myRdvTypeExtendedProperty);

    PropertyName myRdvEmplacementPropertyName = new PropertyName("RdvEmplacement", StandardPropertySet.PUBLIC_STRINGS);
    ExtendedProperty myRdvEmplacementExtendedProperty = new ExtendedProperty(myRdvEmplacementPropertyName, event.getLieu());
    appointment.getExtendedProperties().add(myRdvEmplacementExtendedProperty);

    PropertyName myRdvAdressePropertyName = new PropertyName("RdvAdresse", StandardPropertySet.PUBLIC_STRINGS);
    ExtendedProperty myRdvAdresseExtendedProperty = new ExtendedProperty(myRdvAdressePropertyName, event.getEvent_location());
    appointment.getExtendedProperties().add(myRdvAdresseExtendedProperty);
```

To be sure the custom user properties are created, i use [Outlook SPY](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm)
the screenshot below:

[image]

the code below in the FormRegionShowing :

```
            if (appointmentItem.UserProperties["RdvType"] != null)
        {
            this.TypeRdvComboBox.SelectedItem = appointmentItem.UserProperties["RdvType"].Value;
        }
        if (appointmentItem.UserProperties["RdvEmplacement"] != null)
        {
            this.emplacementRdvComboBox.SelectedItem = appointmentItem.UserProperties["RdvEmplacement"].Value;
        }
        if (appointmentItem.UserProperties["RdvAdresse"] != null)
        {
            this.adresseTextBox.Text = (string)appointmentItem.UserProperties["RdvAdresse"].Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [UserProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869238(v=office.15).aspx) property and [UserProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862196(v=office.15).aspx) class instead. Here is what MSDN states:

*If you use UserProperties.Find to look for a custom property and the call succeeds, it will return a UserProperty object. If it fails, it will return Null. If you use UserProperties.Find to look for a built-in property, specify False for the Custom parameter. If the call succeeds, it will return the property as a UserProperty object. If the call fails, it will return Null. If you specify True for Custom, the call will not find the built-in property and will return Null.*

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
// ... 
private void ShowUserProperties(Outlook.MailItem mail) 
{
   Outlook.UserProperties mailUserProperties = null; 
   Outlook.UserProperty mailUserProperty = null; 
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
   mailUserProperties = mail.UserProperties; 
   try 
   { 
       for (int i = 1; i < = mailUserProperties.Count; i++) 
       { 
           mailUserProperty = mailUserProperties[i]; 
           if (mailUserProperty != null) 
           { 
               builder.AppendFormat("Name: {0} \tValue: {1} \n\r", 
                  mailUserProperty.Name, mailUserProperty.Value); 
               Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailUserProperty); 
               mailUserProperty = null; 
           } 
       } 
       if (builder.Length > 0) 
       { 
          System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString(), 
               "The UserProperties collection"); 
       } 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
       System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
    } 
    finally 
    { 
       if (mailUserProperties != null) 
           Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailUserProperties); 
    } 
 }
```

Read more about that in the [How To: Get Outlook e-mail item’s custom properties – C# and VB.NET samples](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/24/outlook-email-item-custom-properties/) article.

Comment: Thank you for your reponse, I have first of all used the UserProperties to looking for my custom user properties, but i cannot get them. i have created a formRegion where the user properties's value should be displayed... may be i am missing something important

Comment: What code exactly did you use to get property values?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the inspiration, this works:

```
Outlook.MailItem mItem = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
string udpName = "";
string udpValueString = "";
Debug.Print(" mItem.UserProperties.Count: " + mItem.UserProperties.Count);
for (int i = 1; i <= mItem.UserProperties.Count; i++) {
    udpName = mItem.UserProperties[i].Name;
    var udpValue = mItem.UserProperties[i].Value;
    udpValueString = udpValue.ToString();
    Debug.Print(i + ": " + udpName + ": " + udpValueString);
}
```